# How to keep the app in the background after closing - PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, background-process

I would keep my PhoneGap application in background after closing it in order to generate notifications.

I wish my application available on iOS , Android and Windows Phone with notifications.

**Is it possible to execute the JavaScript when the application is in the background ?
How to do ?**

Comment: On iOS only AudioStreamers, VOIP, location tracking or accessory apps are allowed to run in the background. I would suggest you use push notifications. This will also make sure that your app does not drain the users device battery.

Comment: "push notifications" ? 
You mean that ? : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md 
Does it can send a notification to users despite the application is closed ?

Comment: Yes push notification are send from a server to the users device, even if the app is closed.

Comment: @rckoenes Do you have a link to documentation that describes it please ?

Comment: I've never build an app using cordove, but here is the apple documentation:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Comment: @rckoenes You made me look a bit too sure for someone who has never used Cordova! This documentation describes operations of notifiations for native development, not to Cordova. And nothing says when using Cordova and partner notification plugin, it's possible to send notifications on the platform when the application is stopped.

Comment: Cordova is still using all the native code. They just call it from plugins you call from javascript. This the documentation is correct, you will be able to send notification to your Cordova app from a server. You will need a plugin to handle the incoming push notification, it's even in the default phonegap repo: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Comment: @rckoenes True, but I hope it's valid for iOS and Android. From a server, okay, I admit, but there must be a server call at a time from a client, right? If the application is stopped, how to make a server call?

Comment: The idea behind push notification is that the server pushes the notification. Like if you make a messaging app and some one send you a message the server knows this and pushes the notification. You want your client client to invoke the notification you are out of luck because your app is not running thus can't send anything. You will need to build some server logic the send the notifications.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I would like my server to be called every hour, for example, to check whether, at the database, new information concerning an user appeared, and if so, then notification for this user. This is according to this model, this logic, that I would set up notifications. How to put it in place?

Comment: You will need to do it all serverside, if you have this logic in your app it would drain the battery.

Comment: Okay and it's possible to perform iterations hour by hour only server side?

Comment: Ofcourse, you should be able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS there are two kinds of notifications - remote notifications and local notifications. Remote notifications are delivered by your webservice through APNS and require for the device to be connected to the internet.

Local notifications on the other hand are scheduled on device. The most important thing is that both will wake your app for a short time, so it can consume the notification and decide what to do with it. During this time you can of course schedule another local notification.

This - https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications - seems like a good place to start investigating.

Comment: I wish remote notifications I can send from a JS file and which are received by the user when the application is stopped, is in the background or foreground for iOS and Android.